# Populate a "Grouper" column using .withcolumn in scala.spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Trying to populate the `grouper` column like below.  In the table below,  **X** signifies the start of a new record.  So, Each X,Y,Z needs to be grouped.  In MySQL, I would accomplish like:

```
select @x:=1;
update table set grouper=if(column_1='X',@x:=@x+1,@x);
```

I am trying to see if there is a way to do this without using a loop using . With column or something similar.

what I have tried:

```
var group = 1;

val mydf4 = mydf3.withColumn("grouper", when(col("column_1").equalTo("INS"),group=group+1).otherwise(group))
```

[image]

[Example DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJfIe.jpg)

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: var group = 1
         
         val mydf4 = mydf3.withColumn("grouper", when(col("column_1").equalTo("INS"),group+1).otherwise(group))

Comment: additionally:  
var group = 1
         
         val mydf4 = mydf3.withColumn("grouper", when(col("column_1").equalTo("INS"),group=group+1).otherwise(group))

Comment: please update these tryings in the question and please look at my answer below if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `window` function and `row_number()` inbuilt function should get you your desired output

```
val df = Seq(
  Tuple1("X"),
  Tuple1("Y"),
  Tuple1("Z"),
  Tuple1("X"),
  Tuple1("Y"),
  Tuple1("Z")
).toDF("column_1")

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
def windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("column_1").orderBy("column_1")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("grouper", row_number().over(windowSpec)).orderBy("grouper", "column_1").show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+--------+-------+
|column_1|grouper|
+--------+-------+
|X       |1      |
|Y       |1      |
|Z       |1      |
|X       |2      |
|Y       |2      |
|Z       |2      |
+--------+-------+
```

**Note: The last orderBy is just to match the expected output and just for visualization. In real cluster and processing orderBy like that doesn't make sense**

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  What if there can be multiple values between each new record indicator?  like X,Y,Z,A  then X,Y,Z?

Comment: I did try it...Not exactly giving me the output I was hoping for, but it answered the question the way I asked it.  Thanks

Comment: what did you expected A to behave ? what grouper did you had in mind?

Comment: I don't really see where you care about the next instance of X as the MySql code would.  This seems to only care about the X,Y,Z as a group.  But it for sure gives me another tool to explore to try and make it work and I appreciate the answer.